# How much hydrazine does an Iridium satellite start with? How much does it use per year?

Tags: fuel, station-keeping, monopropellant, iridium

Iridium satellites use hydrazine and the spacecraft are expected to last at least 15 years.

How much hydrazine do Iridium satellites start with, and if possible, roughly do they use per year?

Comment: @GremlinWranger That link doesn't refer to Iridium, just Starlink.